# Using lme4 glmer function for unbalanced treatment comparison results in variable length error

Tags: r, lme4

I am using the `lme4` package to run a generalized linear mixed model for proportion data using a binary response. I have unequal sample sizes for my treatments and am getting the following error, which I understand is due to the very fact that I have unequal sample sizes:

> Error in model.frame.default(data = POL3, drop.unused.levels = TRUE,
>   formula = X2 ~  :    variable lengths differ (found for 'Trtmt')

Here is the code that leads to the error:

```
#Excluding NA from the data set
POL3<-na.exclude(POL)
#Indicating the binary response
X2<-cbind(POL3$CHSd, POL3$TotSd-POL3$CHSd)
#Running the model
MMCHS4<-glmer(X2~Trtmt+(1|BSD)+(1|Hgt), family=binomial, data=POL3)
```

I have read that `lme4` can deal with unbalanced samples but can't get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to say for sure without a reproducible example, but you probably need to make sure that the `Trtmt` variable is contained within `POL3` (i.e., that there isn't another `Trtmt` variable lying around in your global workspace).

I would probably implement the model in this way:

```
glmer(CHSd/TotSd~Trtmt+(1|BSD)+(1|Hgt),
      weights=TotSd,
      family=binomial,
      na.action=na.exclude,
      data=POL)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works. Now I have to work around non-integer data which is a whole different beast. Much appreciated your help.